# How to end a session in ExpressJS

Tags: session, node.js, express

I feel like this has to be buried somewhere in the documentation, but I can't find it.

How do you close or end or kill (whatever) a session in ExpressJS?

Comment: express-session package

Answer (score 151, accepted):

### Express 4.x Updated Answer

Session handling is no longer built into Express.  This answer refers to the standard session module:  https://github.com/expressjs/session

To clear the session data, simply use:

```
req.session.destroy();
```

The documentation is a bit useless on this.  It says:

> Destroys the session, removing req.session, will be re-generated next request.
>   `req.session.destroy(function(err) {
>      // cannot access session here
>   })`

This does *not* mean that the current session will be re-loaded on the next request.  It means that a clean empty session will be created in your session store on next request.  (Presumably the session ID isn't changing, but I have not tested that.)

Comment: is there a way to destroy session from sessions and not of the immediate request. For example if i were to implement log me out of all devices functionality i'd need that

Comment: @MuhammadUmer As far as I know, there is no built-in mechanism for destroying an arbitrary session.  You could implement this yourself easily by deleting the keys associated with the session from storage, or by creating your own session wrapper.

Answer (score 100):

Never mind, it's `req.session.destroy();`

Comment: This isn't working for me on express 3.. I'm trying to call ´req.session.destroy()´

Comment: Working fine for me on ExpressJS 3.00. Used `req.session.destroy();` as acidghost did.

Comment: the use of req.session.destroy() also works for me in express 2.5

Comment: Where is this documented? I'm trying to find it.

Answer (score 28):

The question didn't clarify what type of session store was being used.  Both answers seem to be correct.

**For cookie based sessions:**

From http://expressjs.com/api.html#cookieSession

```
req.session = null // Deletes the cookie.
```

**For Redis, etc based sessions:**

```
req.session.destroy // Deletes the session in the database.
```

Comment: req.session.destroy essentially is a wrapper for "delete req.session", see the source-code here: https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/session/session.js

Answer (score 11):

### [Session.destroy(callback)](https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessiondestroycallback)

> Destroys the session and will unset the req.session property. Once complete, the callback will be invoked.

↓ **Secure way** ↓ ✅

```
req.session.destroy((err) => {
  res.redirect('/') // will always fire after session is destroyed
})
```

---

↓ **Unsecure way** ↓ ❌

```
req.logout();
res.redirect('/') // can be called before logout is done
```

Comment: What do if I have flash, because it is causing an error(which is obvious). | UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: req.flash() requires sessions

Comment: In that case I think you could use `req.user = { }`. `password.js` uses `req.user` as far as I remember to keep track of the logged in user.

Answer (score 9):

use,

```
delete req.session.yoursessionname;
```

Comment: I really would like to see a document about this.

Comment: For all those down-voting @Nithin; the session.destroy() function-method as documented on github (github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/session/session.js) uses "delete this.req.session" - it's not exactly @Nithin's answer, but using "delete" is a correct solution as well (and not covered in other answers).

Comment: Is this one is the proper solution? No memory leakage, anything mischievous things won't happen right?

Answer (score 9):

From http://expressjs.com/api.html#cookieSession

To clear a cookie simply assign the session to null before responding:

```
req.session = null
```

Answer (score 6):

#### To end a server-side session

https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessiondestroycallback

```js
req.session.destroy(function(err) {
  // cannot access session here
})
```

Note, this is essentially a wrapper around `delete req.session` as seen in the source code:

https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/session/session.js

```js
defineMethod(Session.prototype, 'destroy', function destroy(fn) {
  delete this.req.session;
  this.req.sessionStore.destroy(this.id, fn);
  return this;
});
```

#### To end a cookie-session

https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session#destroying-a-session

```js
req.session = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
req.session.destroy();
```

The above did not work for me so I did this.

```
req.session.cookie.expires = new Date().getTime();
```

By setting the expiration of the cookie to the current time, the session expired on its own.

Comment: It also works for me, but the expression should be without `.getTime()`: just `req.session.cookie.expires = new Date();`

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the id of a session using `req.session.id` or `req.sessionID` and then pass it to `req.sessionStore.destroy` method like so:

```
const sessionID = req.session.id;
req.sessionStore.destroy(sessionID, (err) => {
  // callback function. If an error occurs, it will be accessible here.
  if(err){
    return console.error(err)
  }
  console.log("The session has been destroyed!")
})
```

[Reference to the `req.sessionStore.destroy` method.](https://github.com/expressjs/session#storedestroysid-callback)

Comment: I tried this but still the session is not deleted from MongoDB's session table.

Answer (score -7):

As mentioned in several places, I'm also not able to get the req.session.destroy() function to work correctly.

This is my work around .. seems to do the trick, and still allows req.flash to be used

```
req.session = {};
```

If you delete or set *req.session = null;* , seems then you can't use req.flash

Comment: This is a security issue, since it doesnt change the session hash