# express-session How to know user already login from another computer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

When user login, I set

```
req.session.username = "....";
```

So, we can know this session has username

But how do I detect if this username is already logged in from another computer and logout (delete session) that another computer

Answer (score 0):

On the server simply create a hash that contains a list of logged in users and the session they are currently using. Store this hash wherever you store stuff (SQL DB, NOSQL DB, flat file, in memory DB, etc).

Upon login, do a quick look at that list (pseudo code):

```
 if( user in logged in list)
    delete the session listed for that user
 otherwise
    create the session
    log session into logged in user list
```

Simple.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a sure way to detect if the user makes a request from another computer. You can use http header `User-Agent` but if both computers have exactly the same user agent and version you would still see them as same.

Using IP is even more error prone because multiple devices may just use same WIFI router or proxy that doesn't set HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR.

However; if a user tries to start a new session (log in) using a user name that already exist you can either refuse the new session or [destroy the old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573256/how-to-end-a-session-in-expressjs).

You need to maintain a list of active sessions in array or redis.

Answer (score 0):

Since you will retrieve the user details when they try to login, you can add a property, `loggedIn`, which will be a `Boolean` with a default value of false in the user schema.

Now you can append an extra control-flow within your login middleware to determine if the user is logged-in or not:

```js
/** Check if user is already logged in */

if (user.loggedIn) {
  let error = {
    status: 401,
    message: 'user already logged in. '
    + 'Please request a password reset if you suspect this is not you.'
  }
  return next(error);
}

// if not, log user in, set the `loggedIn` flag to true and move on.
```

And whenever the user logs out, reset the `loggedIn` flag to false.