# How to control caching, in browser

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a web application in production environement. When the user logout from the website and hits the back button it's should not take him back to the site. Once the user logout all the cache should be erased. I browsed throw some sites, but I didn't get the proper solution. I am not getting how to implement the technique. Any help/advice greatly appreciated.
 Currently what I have done in my backend:

```
app.use(function(req,res){
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); 
    res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
    res.setHeader("Expires", "-1");
```

});

Comment: how do you maintain your session? what type of session store is being used?

Comment: I am storing it in local storage memory

Comment: You are not maintaining a session in the backend? If that so it wrong. Anyone can re login with the same details even if you clear the local storage.

Comment: I'll implement the session in the backend. After that, let me know the further implementation@Hey24sheep

Answer (score 1):

On the browser side

**Local Storage to Manage Session**

```
//To clear everything Or get your item and set it to null
localStorage.clear();
```

**Session Storage to Manage Session**

```
//To clear everything Or get your item and set it to null
sessionStorage.clear();
```

**Cookies to Manage Session**

```
$cookies.remove("userInfo");
```

**NOTE : I would recommend you to use cookies with a Random CSRF Token to protect your clients from CSRF by storing a randomly generated session key in SessionStorage.**

As you currently do not have a session maintained in the back-end I would like you to read this thread :
[How to end a session in ExpressJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573256/how-to-end-a-session-in-expressjs).
And this https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html