# req.session.destroy has no effect

Tags: node.js, express, session, express-session, connect-mongo

I have a NextJS client running on localhost:3001 and a Express/MongoDB server running on localhost:3000.

For authentication I'm using `express-session` with `connect-mongo` like so:

```js
app.use(session({
    secret: 'jordan-peterson-is-a-fraud',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    unset: 'destroy',
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: false
    },
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));
```

On login I set `req.session.user = userID`, which seems to work fine: it registers a new session record in the sessions table in my database, and sends a set-cookie header with the value `connect.sid=<encrypted-session-ID>` to the client which gets stored in a session cookie.

So far, so good.

But on logout it seems that calling `req.session.destroy()` has no effect whatsoever. The client sends a POST with credentials to `/logout` on the server:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3000/logout', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include'
})
```

And the server does seem to receive a correct `req` object that includes:

```
{
    ...
    sessionID: '<encrypted-session-ID>',
    session: Session {
      cookie: {
        path: '/',
        _expires: null,
        originalMaxAge: null,
        httpOnly: false
      }
    }
    ...
}
```

The console also prints `[Function: destroy]` when I log `req.session.destroy`. But nothing happens when I call it. The database is unchanged - with the session record still there from the login.

```js
router.all('/logout', async function(req, res){
    if (req.session) {
        req.session.destroy();
        return res.end();
    }
}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Show the code where you call the destroy function. Also see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573256/how-to-end-a-session-in-expressjs

Comment: I've updated the question like you asked.

Comment: try `req.logout();` then do a redirect

Comment: @o01 Have you found a solution? I have an IDENTICAL problem. Nothing happens on `req.session.destroy();`. The database (PostgreSQL in my case) is unchanged. I've been trying for days now!

Answer (score 1):

You can use delete req.session.user;

Comment: This kind of worked. At least the `user` property was removed from the session record in the database. But the rest of the session record is still there?

Comment: Could you please check if delete req.session works.

Answer (score -1):

```
req.session.destroy(req.sessionID)
```

Comment: req.session.destroy() accepts only a callback function.